React Hook Form: form.reset works but form.resetField doesn't
asset.attributes can change externally, so I need to let the React Hook Form know:
useEffect(() => {
  if (asset) {
    const initialAttrs = Object.entries(asset.attributes || {}).map(
      ([key, value]) => ({
        key,
        value: value ? String(value) : '',
      }),
    );

    setAttrs(initialAttrs);

    form.reset({
      name: asset.name || '',
      description: asset.description || '',
      fields: asset.fields?.[0]?.id || '',
      persons: asset.persons?.[0]?.id || '',
      attributes: asset.attributes || {},
      tags: asset.tags || [],
      contentAssets: asset.contentAssets || [],
      files: [], // Reset files if necessary
    });
  }
}, [asset, form]);

This effectively resets the form. However, this way I'm repeating the default values twice (I'm setting the default values before the useEffect()). So I thought I should just reset asset.attributes:
form.resetField('attributes', {
  defaultValue: asset.attributes || {},
});

However, for some reason, asset.attributes is not being reset like it was with form.reset(). What could be the issue here?

Probaly because of the field you’re trying to reset with form.resetField() is correctly registered in the form.
1.Register Fields with register:
const MyForm = () => {
   const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }, reset, 
  setValue } = useForm();
   return (
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input {...register('attributes')} />
        {/* Other fields */}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>
    )};
    

2.Use controller for controlled component
const MyForm = () => {
const { control, handleSubmit, reset, setValue } = useForm();
...
return (
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <Controller
    name="attributes"
    control={control}
    defaultValue=""
    render={({ field }) => <TextField {...field} />}
  />
  {/* Other fields */}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
);
};

Another way: Manual Field Update
form.setValue('attributes', asset.attributes || {});

